# In how many ways can three soldiers line up for a picture, if each one is given the choice of wearing or not wearing his cap

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

My instructor provided this answer:

> A  soldier  wearing  his  hat  will appear different  in  picture compared  to  >when  he  is not  wearing  his  hat. Thus  we need to determine permutations of >$6$ objects taken $3$ at a time. Hence, $P(6, 3) = 120$

I don't understand this solution b/c it treats the solders wearing or not wearing cap as distinct which can both line up at the same time.

I think the solution should be:

> > Give the three places an ordering, $1,2,3$, the first place can be occupied by $3 $ soldiers, once selected, he has the choice of wearing or not wearing his cap which can be done in $2$ ways. Reasoning the same way, we have a total of $(3 \times 2) \times (2 \times 2) \times (1 \times 2)= 48$= ways

Answer (score 1):

Think of Soldiers as letters 1-3.

There are 3! ways to arrange the digits, or 6 possibilities.
123, 132, 213, 231, 312, and 321.

Now Let's consider that **A** means soldier 1 has his hat on, and **a** that he has his hat off (We're substituting a letter for each digit case for each 1 in the previous 6 possibilities.) So for each of the 6 arrangements, each soldier could have his hat on or off.

e.g. for 123 just considering soldier 1 we get a23 and A23.

The result is $2^3 * 6 $ possibilities or 48.